# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null- when setting the innerhtml to a string from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following code I am trying to set the cat names in a way that doesn't hardcode them to the html. Because of that I am using an array. however whenever I try to set the innerHTML properties to catNames[0] or catNames[1] I get an error. I don't know why it doesn't evaluate that array and find the string and put that on the page.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cat Clicker</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div>
    <!-- name -->
    <h1 id="creatname1">y</h1>

    <!-- clickable image -->
    <img id="cat" src="img/cat.jpg">

    <!-- text -->
    <p> You have clicked
        <strong id="counter1">0</strong> times
    </p>
    </div>


<div>
    <!-- name -->
    <h1 id="createname2">x</h1>

    <!-- clickable image -->
    <img id="cat2" src="img/cat2.jpg">

    <!-- text -->
    <p> You have clicked <strong id="counter2">0</strong> times</p>

</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
                       (function(){
   var image = document.getElementById('cat'), image2=     
    document.getElementById('cat2'),
    clicks1= document.getElementById('counter1'),clicks2=                         
    document.getElementById('counter2'),
    counterNumber1=0, counterNumber2=0, catNames=["Javi","Esteban"], name1=    
    document.getElementById('createname1'), name2=  
    document.getElementById('createname2');

name1.innerHTML= catNames[0];
name2.innerHTML= catNames[1];

function imageClickHandler() {
    counterNumber1++;
    clicks1.innerHTML= counterNumber1;
}

function imageClickHandler2() {
    counterNumber2++;
    clicks2.innerHTML= counterNumber2;
}



image.addEventListener('click',imageClickHandler,false);
image2.addEventListener('click',imageClickHandler2,false);

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a bit your code (actually, I intended the lines and make single variable declarations to be more readable.

The error was in the `id` you were using. Specifically, in your HTML code you define the `id` `creatname1` and you try to select the element with id `createname1`.

```js
(function(){
   var image = document.getElementById('cat');
   var image2 = document.getElementById('cat2');
   var clicks1 = document.getElementById('counter1');
   var clicks2 = document.getElementById('counter2');
   var counterNumber1=0;
   var counterNumber2=0;
   var catNames=["Javi","Esteban"];
   var name1 = document.getElementById('createname1');
   var name2 = document.getElementById('createname2');

   name1.innerHTML= catNames[0];
   name2.innerHTML= catNames[1];

   function imageClickHandler() {
       counterNumber1++;
      clicks1.innerHTML= counterNumber1;
   }

   function imageClickHandler2() {
       counterNumber2++;
       clicks2.innerHTML= counterNumber2;
   }



image.addEventListener('click',imageClickHandler,false);
image2.addEventListener('click',imageClickHandler2,false);

})();
```

```html
 <div>
    <!-- name -->
    <h1 id="createname1">y</h1>

    <!-- clickable image -->
    <img id="cat" src="img/cat.jpg">

    <!-- text -->
    <p> You have clicked
        <strong id="counter1">0</strong> times
    </p>
    </div>


<div>
    <!-- name -->
    <h1 id="createname2">x</h1>

    <!-- clickable image -->
    <img id="cat2" src="img/cat2.jpg">

    <!-- text -->
    <p> You have clicked <strong id="counter2">0</strong> times</p>

</div>
```